# mod_cache_disk define max disk usage

Tags: apache, caching, diskcache

I'm using mod_cache_disk to cache some data via apache, I have a 150gb avaiable but mod_cache_disk is only caching 2gb.

I couldn't find a directive that explicit the disk usage, how can I do this?
My current configuration is:

```
   CacheEnable disk /dash/
   CacheRoot "/var/cache/hls_cache"
   CacheDirLevels 5
   CacheDirLength 4
   CacheIgnoreCacheControl on
   CacheMaxExpire 86400
   CacheIgnoreQueryString on
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there isn't such directive however there is a tool called htcacheclean that performs what I want to do.

Link can be found here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htcacheclean.html